# Non-teflon rice cooker reccomendations

Tags: rice, rice-cooker

I am looking to get rid of the teflon rice cooker I have (it is getting a lot of scratches, and I am worried about where that teflon is going). What should one look for in a good rice cooker that does not have a teflon coating?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a brand recommendation

Comment: @rumtscho I edited the question to make it more general.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I am a bit unsure about the reopen. The edit you made goes indeed in the direction we would like to see when a recommendation question is asked. Neither the old answer nor your new one are actually addressing the new version, though. Would you be willing to rework your answer, or should we delete both and make the question a free slate for new answers, or is there another alternative I'm overlooking?

Comment: The old answer does not answer the question, before or after the edit.  I feel like my answer does address it partially, but lacks experience about the specific type of rice.  IMHO there is no reason to delete answers, they get up or down votes and that takes care of it.

Comment: If the teflon is scratching, you need to get softer mixing spoons. Nylon, not Bakelite.

Answer (score 2):

I quickly checked the models that Cook's Illustrated recommended, and all of them either say they're Teflon (aka PTFE) or are a non-specified non-stick (which probably means PTFE).

Also, PTFE isn't toxic, at least not until heated in excess of 200°C ([details at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teflon#Safety)).

Comment: Good points. I guess my real issue is with cheap teflon that flakes away too quickly.

Comment: @Zombies: It could also be that you're damaging the Teflon somehow; are you using metal utensils on it, for example?

Comment: Nope! It is just really cheap the whole rice cooker was like $15 at target.

Comment: @Zombies: Ok, I've had to cheap bread pans like that (well, they were much cheaper than $15, and Walmart not Target), where the non-stick just wasn't bound to the metal properly. Slightly less cheap ones didn't have the issue. Unfortunately, it looks like good rice cookers are more than slightly less cheap :-( You could always use a small sauce pot…

Comment: Don't buy very cheap kitchen ware. I paid more than $100 for my rice cooker. The teflon is good as new after more than 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of rice cookers available with stainless steel pans.  A quick Google finds several for around $20(US).  No worries about Teflon (aka PTFE).